# Java Threading workers

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans

I am trying to run workerThread so that all the workers start their job i have added my code on workforce start() however when i run it, it gives them in order from 0 to 19 so have i done something wrong there as when the thread starts it usually doesnt give them in order and i have tried deleting the workerThread i = new thread and put system.out.println("worker" + workerThread[i]" instead but it gives outcome of Worker Thread[Thread-0,5,main]. How can i make this better.

Worker.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Worker implements Runnable {

private final int id;  // Unique worker ID.

private final JobStack jobStack;  // Reference to the job stack.
private final ResourceStack resourceStack;  // Reference to the resource stack.

private Job job;  // Job being processed.
private Resource[] resources;  // Resources being used for job being processed.

private boolean busy;  // Indicates the status of the worker. True when they are working (executing jobs) and false when there are no more jobs left to execute.

private final Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> jobsCompleted;  // The job record of the worker. Stores each job's ID and the IDs of the resources used for each job.

// Constructor.
public Worker(int theId, JobStack theJobStack, ResourceStack theResourceStack) {
    id = theId;
    jobStack = theJobStack;
    resourceStack = theResourceStack;
    job = null;
    busy = true;
    jobsCompleted = new TreeMap<>();
}


/// UNDER CONSTRUCTION /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


public void run() {
    try
    {
        System.out.println ("Thread " + id +" is running");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Throwing an exception
        System.out.println ("Exception is caught");
    }
}
```

}

workforce.java

```
public class Workforce {

private final Worker[] pool;  // The worker population.
private int workerCount = 0;  // Used to generate each worker's ID and to keep a record of the number of workers in the workforce.

Thread[] workerThreads;

private final JobStack jobStack;  // Reference to the job stack.
private final ResourceStack resourceStack;  // Reference to the resource stack.

// Constructor.
public Workforce(int size, JobStack theJobStack, ResourceStack theResourceStack) {
    jobStack = theJobStack;
    resourceStack = theResourceStack;

    pool = new Worker[size];
    for(int i=0; i<pool.length; i++) {
        pool[i] = new Worker(workerCount, jobStack, resourceStack);
        workerCount++;
    }

    workerThreads = new Thread[pool.length];
    for(int i=0; i<workerThreads.length; i++) {
        workerThreads[i] = new Thread(pool[i]);
    }
}


/// UNDER CONSTRUCTION /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// Starts all the worker threads.
public void start() {

    for(int i=0; i<pool.length; i++) {
       workerThreads[i] = new Thread(pool[i]);
        workerThreads[i].start();
    }



}

// Checks whether all workers have finished.
public boolean allWorkersFinished() {
    return false;
}

// Prints the job record of all workers.
public void printJobRecords() {
    ;
}
}
```

Comment: The `for` loop in your `start()` should give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since it's using `<=pool.length`. It's also extremely unclear what your question is.

Comment: Basicly i want my output to be something like Worker 4 started.
Worker 6 started. etc however when i do it it goes in order so worker 1 started so i am saying have i done something wrong there that gives it like this and also should do i have to use for loo[ to make my workerThread start.

Comment: Why would you expect it to go not in order, when your for loop executes in order, as it normally does?

Comment: I have got it now thanks anyways for taking time, just edited to right one